# How to organize waiting until asynchronous file download is complete?

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous, webclient

My Silverlight application must implement three actions after Button is clicked. The actions must be implemented consecutively. The second action is file downloading. I use `WebClient` class to download a file. How can I organize waiting for the file to be finished downloading?

```
void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {     
  action_1(); //Some action;
  action_2(); //Downloading a file;
  //Waiting for the file to be finished downloading. How can I organize it?;
  action_3() //Another action;
}

void action_2() { 
   WebClient client = new WebClient();
   client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(file_OpenReadCompleted);
   client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("My uri", UriKind.Relative));
}

void file_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) {
  //Actions with obtained stream;
}
```

Of course, I can move call of `action_3()` from `button_Click()` to the end of `file_OpenReadCompleted()` function. But I don't want to do it, because it makes the code unclear.

Comment: Which version of the framework are you using?

Comment: I use C# 4.0, MVS 2013, .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: Can you use `WebClient.OpenReadTaskAsync` instead, which would let you `await` the result. If your other methods are also asynchronous you could again await those.

Comment: Unfortunately Silverlight version of `WebClient` doesn't have `WebClient.OpenReadTaskAsync` method.

Comment: Interesting - I didn't know that. However I did find [this](http://10rem.net/blog/2012/05/22/using-async-and-await-in-silverlight-5-and-net-4-in-visual-studio-11-with-the-async-targeting-pack) which might help.

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel! I installed a package from the paper that you advised. After that `OpenReadTaskAsync` method appeared and I could apply your approach.

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel! I installed a package from the paper that you advised. After that `OpenReadTaskAsync` method appeared and I could apply your approach.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you'd like to put the code calling `WebClient.OpenReadTaskAsync` into a separate method I believe that would need to be an `async` method too and you'd need to `await` the result of that. Once you use `async` it has to propagate all the way up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [WebClient.OpenReadTaskAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159420(v=vs.110).aspx). Your code would then become:

```
async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {     
    action_1(); //Some action;

    using (var wc = new WebClient()) // not sure if you can dispose at this scope 
                                     // or need to execute action_3 inside here too
    {
        var stream = await wc.OpenReadTaskAsync(new Uri("My uri", UriKind.Relative));
        .. do your thing here
    }

    action_3() //Another action;
}
```